# Como permitir digitar apenas "yes" ou "no" com RegExp em uma input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Qual a expressão regular para permitir digitar apenas yes ou no em um campo.?

Ele esta permitindo repetir os caracteres e não pode.

```
$('body').on("keyup",".logical",function(){
$(this).unbind('keyup').bind('keyup',function(e){ //vou buscar o evento keyup - quando o usuário solta a tecla

            var thisVal = $(this).val(); // atribuo o valor do campo a variável local
            var tempVal = "";

            for(var i = 0; i<thisVal.length; i++){
                if(RegExp(/^[s,y,e,n,o]$/).test(thisVal.charAt(i))){ // aqui estou usando uma expressão regular para limitar a entrada de apenas numeros ou seja digitos entre 0 e 9
                    tempVal += thisVal.charAt(i); //caso atenda a condição de ser um digito numérico, atribuo a uma variável temporária

                    if(e.keyCode == 8){
                        tempVal = thisVal.substr(0,i); //o keyCode == 8 é para eu poder usar o backspace para apagar algum numero indesejado.
                    }                       
                }
            }           
            $(this).val(tempVal); // ao terminar, atribuo o valor validado ao valor do campo passado para testar
        });});
```

Comment: Talvez o componente mais indicado fossem dois radiobuttons, não?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A expressão regular que verifica se uma string é "yes" ou "no" é `/^(yes|no)$/`. Porém eu acredito que conceitualmente você esta usando o componente errado para esta tarefa.

**Solução:**

```js
$('.apenasYesNo').bind('keypress', function(e) {
  var jaDigitado = $(e.target).val(),
      letra = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

  if(!/^(y|ye|yes|n|no)$/.test(jaDigitado + letra)) {
    e.preventDefault();   
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="apenasYesNo" />
<input class="apenasYesNo" />
<input class="apenasYesNo" />
```

**EDIT:** Você pode melhorar esta implementação permitindo que o usuário edite um caracter no inicio do texto atualizando o código para:

```
function permitirApenasHorario(e) {
    var jaDigitado = $(e.target).val(),
        letra = String.fromCharCode(e.which),
        posicaoDoCursor = getCaretPosition(e.target),
        textoPretendido = insert(jaDigitado, posicaoDoCursor, letra);

    if(!regExpDeHorario.test(textoPretendido)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Onde `getCaretPosition` (retirado [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2897229/91403)) é:

```
function getCaretPosition(field) {
    var caretPosition = 0;

    if (document.selection) { 
        //Suporte ao IE
        field.focus();

        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveStart('character', -field.value.length);
        caretPosition = range.text.length;
    } else if (field.selectionStart || field.selectionStart == '0') {
        // Suporte ao Firefox 
        caretPosition = field.selectionStart;
    }

    return caretPosition;
}
```

E `insert` é:

```
function insert(string, index, value) {
    return [
        string.substring(0, index),
        value,
        string.substring(index, string.length)
    ].join('');
}
```

*Exemplo: Esta melhoria é útil se você deseja usar esta funcionalidade para forçar o usuário a entrar um valor de horário correto, e ele eventualmente pode querer editar as horas sem apagar os minutos. Experimente com a regExp: `var regExpDeHorario = /^([0-2]|([0-2]|[01]\d|2[0-3])|([0-2]|[01]\d|2[0-3]):|([0-2]|[01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5])|([0-2]|[01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5])\d)$/;`*

Comment: muito bom! `+1`

Comment: Muito bom, era isso mesmo que precisava!. Obrigado

Comment: mais uma duvida ja esta como 'yes' teria uma maneira de digitar por sima ? sem precisar apagar para digitar o 'no'?

Comment: Como assim, @Gustavo? Explica melhor

Comment: ao copilar seu codigo, quando voce digita no campo o "yes" você precisa apagar o "yes" para digitar o "no" ele nao apaga automaticamente , se eu substituir o  e.preventDefault(); por $(e.target).val(""); funciona mais ou menos.

Comment: @Gustavo talvez a minha edição te ajude! De uma olhada, me diz se vc entendeu...!