# Validação de campos em javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou com um pequeno problema que é o seguinte:

Em determinados campos de um formulário, o usuário não pode digitar letras, caracteres especiais (exceto `.`, `+` e `-`). Quando o usuário pressiona o botão `.` uma vez ele não permite digitar o ponto novamente. Caso ele digite o ponto novamente os números que aparecem após o ponto devem ser selecionados.

É possível fazer isto amigos?

Comment: Você pode se inspirar nessa pergunta/resposta [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42812/como-permitir-digitar-apenas-yes-ou-no-com-regexp-em-uma-input)! É só você pegar o evento `keypress`e fazer a validação correta para impedir que o usuário insira o caracter. Para algo mais cimplexo voce pode procurar um plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, existem muitos componentes na web para isto. Eu uso o [Masked Input Plugin](http://bit.ly/1eUKATA) para jQuery, mas existem muitos outros como o [jQuery Mask Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/). Coloque `jQuery Mask` no Google que você acha vários. Caso não use o jQuery, existem também componentes que não necessitam dele, mas eu recomendo fortemente que use ele.

Comment: Quanto ao input, consegui resolver isso. Agora o problema é em relação à selecionar o texto depois do . caso o usuário pressione o ponto novamente

Comment: se vc faz isso programaticamente, sem usar componente, vai ter que lidar com todos esses problemas que o desenvolvedor do componente já resolveu pra vc. :)